Amadeus Python SDK discrepancies in airport suggestions
I have been trying to get airport IATA/recommendations/search using the Amadeus Airports search endpoint with lat, long codes as follows, but when I search for Prague it returns airports from Munich which is way far from Prague. But when I later try using PRG for flight_offers_search it works fine [Just tried this to see if there are any PRG airports supported].
I don't understand why I am unable to get any airports from Prague. Please help me solve this issue. Below is the python SDK code I use.
from amadeus import Client
amadeus = Client(
    client_id='YOUR_ID',
    client_secret='YOUR_SECRET')

#airport search test
response = amadeus.reference_data.locations.airports.get(
                latitude=50.0755381,
                longitude=14.4378005,
            )
print(response.data)

#offer search test
kwargs_trip_purpose = {
            "originLocationCode": "PRG",
            "destinationLocationCode": "SFO",
            "departureDate": "2024-08-22", #Please change dates accordingly
            "returnDate": "2024-08-30", #Please change dates accordingly
            "adults": 1,
            "currencyCode": "USD"
        }
offers_search_output = amadeus.shopping.flight_offers_search.get(**kwargs_trip_purpose).data

